# Simple error checking user input

Tags: java, fractions

I'm having trouble with getting my methods to add, subtract, and divide fractions. I have the multiplication part already I'm just having trouble getting the correct output when I add. please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong I am new in Java and I'm still learning. here's what I got so far.``

```
private int numer;
private int denom;

public Fraction(int num, int den) {
    numer = num;
    denom = den;

simplify();
}
public int findGcd(int a, int b) {
    int temp;
    while (b != 0) {
        temp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

void simplify() {
    int gcd = findGcd(numer, denom);
    numer /= gcd;
    denom /= gcd;
}
public int getNumer() {
    return numer;
}
public int getDenom() {
    return denom;
}

Fraction add(Fraction x) {
    Fraction answer;

    if (x.getDenom() == denom) {
        answer = new Fraction(x.getNumer() + numer, denom);
    } else {
        denom = this.getDenom() * x.getDenom();
        numer = this.getNumer() * x.getDenom() + x.getNumer()
                * this.getDenom();

        return new Fraction(numer, denom);

    }
    return answer;
}

Fraction subtract(Fraction x) {
    Fraction answer;

    if (x.getDenom() == denom) {
        answer = new Fraction(x.getNumer() - numer, denom);
    } else {
        denom = this.getDenom() * x.getDenom();
        numer = this.getNumer() * x.getDenom() - x.getNumer()
                * this.getDenom();
        answer = new Fraction(numer, denom);
    }
    return answer;
}

Fraction mult(Fraction x) {
    Fraction answer;

    denom = this.getDenom() * x.getDenom();
    numer = this.getNumer() * x.getNumer();
    answer = new Fraction(numer, denom);

    return answer;
}

Fraction div(Fraction x) {
    Fraction answer;

    denom = this.getDenom() * x.getNumer();
    numer = this.getNumer() * x.getDenom();
    answer = new Fraction(numer, denom);
    return answer;
}
```

When I input 2 fractions it returns a fraction but it is not the correct answer. What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

If I use small fractions for example 1/2 and 3/4 it still gives me wrong answer.  For additions it prints out 7/2, subtraction 1/2, and division 3/1.  So I don't think that has to do anything with being an `int` or a `float` number.

Comment: Which of the functions are incorrect?  Can you privide test cases and results for Add, Mulitply, Divide, and Subtract

Comment: subtraction addition and division

Answer (score 2):

In your functions, you are overwriting the values of the numer and denom.  Change:

```
denom = this.getDenom() * x.getDenom(); 
numer = this.getNumer() * x.getDenom() - x.getNumer() 
            * this.getDenom(); 
answer = new Fraction(numer, denom);
```

to

```
int newdenom = this.getDenom() * x.getDenom(); 
int newnumer = this.getNumer() * x.getDenom() - x.getNumer() 
            * this.getDenom(); 
answer = new Fraction(newnumer, newdenom);
```

Comment: i dont think this is the issue because i tryed your the method you told me but it didnt work. still getting the wrong answers for the addition subtraction and division of the fractions

Comment: If the math is right, then Brandon's way is right, because you override the denom value (1st Line in Brandons quote), so `this.getDenom()` will return the new value of it, and I bet you still need the old value at that point.